# JQuery $.get returns 404 undefined from Self hosting Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am just starting to look at web-api, and have set up a small self hosting projects. I set up a basic controller, and it returned results when I tried pointing to it in my browser.

Now when I try calling it using the jquery.get

eg

```
$.get("http://<my ip>:8082/api/stats/single/1/i")                 
    .done(function(result) {
        alert("results");
     })
    .error(function(result) { 
       alert(result.status + " " + result.responseText); }
 );};
```

I get an error (404 undefined)

If I look at the result from the above in fiddle I do see the json results I expect, and the raw header is as follows...

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Length: 415
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
 Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 13:04:03 GMT
```

If I try the jquery on another remote server that I know provides test data, the .get returns correctly. I do notice there is a lot more in the raw header from this server...

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: no-cache 
  Pragma: no-cache
  Content-Length: 431
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Expires: -1
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  Set-Cookie:   ARRAffinity=462716b27beb795c09df205e893d3e263b1ec9b710c92f7c4203f4b63ac1aed2;Path=/;Domain=sampleservices.devexpress.com
   Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=j4sdehjie1h0cv2rukxnudw3; path=/; HttpOnly
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Set-Cookie: WAWebSiteSID=14a8502027ea4cc3a9e65036ed421c5e; Path=/; HttpOnly
   Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 13:26:52 GMT
```

Would anyone have any ideas why my web-api test is not working with a call using the $.get??

(answer to question)..

When I use my query in chrome I get

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 405
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 05:34:33 GMT

<`ArrayOfStateController.State xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApiEquipmentStatus"><StateController.State><Description>state1 description</Description><Name>state1</Name></StateController.State><StateController.State><Description>state2 description</Description><Name>state2</Name></StateController.State></ArrayOfStateController.State>`

And when I run the jquery, I see the following in fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 107
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 05:35:58 GMT

[{"Name":"state1","Description":"state1 description"},{"Name":"state2","Description":"state2 description"}]
```

[EDIT]

From suggestions I have tried the below..

```
 enter code here


enter code here
$.ajax.crossDomain = true;          
                    getSingle = function () {
                        $.getJSON("http://<ip>/api/state/single/1/i?callback=process", 
                            {header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'})
                            .done(function (result) {
                                var process = function(data) {
                                    $("#results").text(data.toString());
                                };

                            })
                            .error(function (result) {
                                $("#results").text(result.status + " " + result.responseText);
                            });
                    };
```

If I look in Chrome console window, I still see

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<ip>:8082/api/state/single/1/i?callback=process. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "
```

I have spent the whole day Googling on this subject, and nothing seems to point to how to solve this (at intro level)

Comment: And what do you see it you go to `http://<my ip>:8082/api/stats/single/1/i`?

Comment: Put the answer as an edit in the original question

Comment: if you are using `<my ip>` in the `AJAX` call and point your browser to `localhost` you may run into the `same origin policy` challenge with you call

Comment: I have actually tried, my ip, localhost, and my machine name. None of them work when I use the .get, all of them work when I "call" the service in the browser. Also, with the .get call, the service is called, *eg hit break point), and in fiddle can see the coeect json returned. Just $.get reports an error. I am lost here, and not sure how to debug or proceed with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working.

Being new to the web-api, all I wanted to know was how to set this header information, and all I needed to do, was rather than just return results, was to wrap it in a HttpResponseMessage and return that, eg:

```
const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

public HttpResponseMessage GetAllProducts()
        {          
          var results = GetProducts();
          HttpResponseMessage  response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
          response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, "*");
          return response;
        }
```

Thank you others for your contributions at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

Like Bart said, you "you may run into the same origin policy challenge with you call", maybe because you use the port 8082 in your ajax query and not in your origin url. you can:

- don't use that port
- use jsonp
- use the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" with "`http://<my ip>:8082`" in the origin page AND use $.ajax() "crossDomain" option set to true.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have tried $.ajax.crossDomain = true;         
         getSingle = function () {
             $.getJSON("http://localhost/api/state/single/1/i?callback=process", 
                 {header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'})
                 .done(function (result) {
                     var process = function(data) {
                         $("#results").text(data.toString());
                     };

Comment: I have put the above as an edit in the question (new to stack overflow, replace localhost with <ip> as I could not see how to surround in the code block

Comment: I hadn't but I just did, stil the same

Comment: Sorry, it was not in the ajax call that you have to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but in the http headers of the page who make the ajax call. I don't know how to do that with asp, but it should be trivial.

Comment: Yeah, it is comical, this is discussed in so much detail everywhere, and there are lots of quotes of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in headers, etc, (but never in the exact context of where to use it) all sorts of articles on what it is all about, but no real examples of exactly where to use this! In my case, it is the most basic thing ever, a simple out of the box service, and a simple jquery get, *all on the same machine*! Nothing else, and it just doesn't work.